# How to store the username of the LoginName Control from the LoginView into a textbox control

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

I have a submission form developed in ASP.NET C# and I'm trying to store the username of the LoginName control into a text box control. In simplest terms, make the username display inside a textbox. I'm able to store the current date into a textbox control using the following:

```
dateCreated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

...with dateCreated being the id of the Textbox control and it works fine.

The following is what I'm attempting to do for the LoginName control:

```
createdBy.Text = LoginName1.ClientID;
```

...with createdBy being the id of the textbox control am attempting to store the username into. The following is the design for my LoginView Control:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
   You are not Logged in, Click the login link to sign in
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
   You are Logged in. Welcome, <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server"/>
<LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

but, I'm stuck as to what definition I'm to apply to the LoginName1. Could I please get some help as to how I'm to accomplish this task? I'm new to .Net, Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't capture LoginName content in this way. But the following code will do the job:

```
createdBy.Text = User.Identity.Name;
```